# to display weather forecast for currentday,next day and day after next day in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, weather

Hi 
i want to create a weather application.My weather application is such that when user clicks on weather tab weather details of the current location should be displayed in table view.For the same current location,weather details for the current day ,next day and day after next day should be displayed in tableview.please anybody give me any sort of code or any link on how this is possible in iphone.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use `NSDate` ,

First Construct an `NSDate` object with current time

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
NSString *currentDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
```

Now `currentDate` is the string object, you can display it with `UILabel`  on screen,

likewise you could create date and get the string object for Next day .....

**WeatherAPI**

These are not iPhone specific, but free weather APIs.

**[NOAA REST Interface](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/rest.php)**

Example: http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?zipCodeList=90210&product=time-series&begin=2004-01-01T00:00:00&end=2013-04-21T00:00:00&maxt=maxt&mint=mint

**[Yahoo! Weather Forecast RSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)**

Example: http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=90210

**Google Weather API** - documentation URL for this?

Example: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=90210

**[Weather Underground API](http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML)**

Example: http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML/index.xml?query=90210

**[Weather Channel](http://www.weather.com/services/xmloap.html)** - Requires signup

Example: found [sample code at github](http://github.com/jdpace/weatherman/tree/master). *Ruby gem for accessing the Weather Channel XML API*

**[WeatherAPI](http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/documentation)** (Norway)

Example: http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.6/?lat=34;lon=-118

Comment: i dont want to display current date, next date .i want weather details fetched from web service that should be displayed in tableview for current day,next day

Comment: jhaliya, how can i use this apis to create weather application

Answer (score 1):

To display weather information in application  you can use the following weather data feed(supports the following formats XML/JSON/CSV).

[Weather API](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/)

You can use TouchXML for parsing XML(if the data feed return type is XML fromat).

[TouchXML](http://foobarpig.com/iphone/touchxml-installation-guide.html)