# How to get weather forecast for a location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to get weather report (**forecast for the next 5 days**) of the **current location**.

I did a research about weather APIs for iOS like Yahoo, Google, Weather.com .... But I was unable to find an **example project** which uses weather API (with forecasting)

If there is any **example project** or any free weather report services to use in my application.
Please tell me

Thank u in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with just writing your own project based around the API you found?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is so simple .. you have to look for the API , pass it the required parameters `Date range - country etc ..` .. this will return an xml buffer .. then you can use and objective c XML parser .. Try to google `parse xml objective c` and you'll find a lot of articles .

Here's a sort of APIs form an old SOF topic (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775488/to-display-weather-forecast-for-currentday-next-day-and-day-after-next-day-in-ip).

```
NOAA REST Interface

Example: http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?zipCodeList=90210&product=time-series&begin=2004-01-01T00:00:00&end=2013-04-21T00:00:00&maxt=maxt&mint=mint

Yahoo! Weather Forecast RSS

Example: http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=90210

Google Weather API - documentation URL for this?

Example: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=90210

Weather Underground API

Example: http://api.wunderground.com/auto/wui/geo/GeoLookupXML/index.xml?query=90210

Weather Channel - Requires signup

Example: found sample code at github. Ruby gem for accessing the Weather Channel XML API

WeatherAPI (Norway)

Example: http://api.yr.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.6/?lat=34;lon=-118
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look at Apple's weather widget and see if you can observe how the widget communicates with weather.yahoo.com or just use it through WebKit or something.  It's in /Library/Widget/Weather.wdgt